# Why Mouse Hovering over H1 doest not trigger CSS effect on H2 to start?

Tags: css, css-selectors, hover

Given are two headings, Heading `h1` and Heading `h2`.

The `h2` has a nice underline effect set on her that shows on mouse over.

I would like to be able to hover on the `h2` **as well as** `h1`, for the underline effect to start under `h2` header.

The mouse over hover effect works when hovering over `h2`, but not when hovering over `h1`.

What is the reason that hovering over `h1` does not trigger the underlining effect under `h2`?

```css
h2:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 10%;
    padding-top: 1em;
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
    transition: 0.25s;
}

h2:hover:after{ /* Works as expected */
    width: 100%;
}

h1:hover h2:after{ /* Broken, does not trigger the h2 underline */
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" >
<hgroup>
<div>
    <div>
    <h1>Heading One</h1>
    </div>
</div>
</hgroup>
</a>



<h2>Heading Two</h2>
```

Comment: That's not how CSS works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you've written your selector, its trying to target h2's that are children of the h1, but your html structure doesn't reflect that.

One option is to add a selector to the outer `a` and then target the adjacent h2 with the `+` [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator)

Here's a snippet showing that:

```css
h2:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 10%;
  padding-top: 1em;
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

h2:hover:after {
  /* Works as expected */
  width: 100%;
}

a:hover+h2:after {
  /* hover applied to the containing element so we can target the adjacent h2 */
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <hgroup>
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>Heading One</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </hgroup>
</a>



<h2>Heading Two</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

`h1:hover h2` selector requires `h2` to  be the child of the `h1`. You can apply hover styles only for descendants elements.

Answer (score 1):

Since the h2 isnt nested into the h1 you cant access it in css. Adding a bit of javascript does the trick.

```js
const h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
const h2 = document.querySelector('h2');

h1.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  h2.classList.add('active');
})
h1.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
  h2.classList.remove('active');
})
```

```css
    h2:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        width: 10%;
        padding-top: 1em;
        border-bottom: 4px solid black;
        transition: 0.25s;
    }

    h2:hover:after,h2.active:after { /* Works as expected */
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<a href="#" >
<hgroup>
<div>
    <div>
    <h1>Heading One</h1>
    </div>
</div>
</hgroup>
</a>

<h2>Heading Two</h2>
```